# The best way to change the text on a webpage without refreshing

Tags: php, javascript, html

I'm trying to emulate the upvote/downvote system used on the SE sites. Each of my pages have a score which users can upvote or downvote.

The arrows are images with `onclick` links to javascript functions. I need to find a way to dynamically change the score without refreshing the page and then run a script (probably PHP) to increment the score in the server's data files.

Is javascript the best way to do this? I'm not that big of a fan of letting users see the source for my functions.

Comment: It is the only sane way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only possible using Javascript.

Don't worry about users seeing the source; **as long as the server is secure** and well-designed, it won't do any harm.
You should only implement display and validation logic in Javascript; everything must be validated again on the server.

Comment: I think I'll implement it right in javascript for now, but upgrade to AJAX later on. Thank you.

Comment: That doesn't make sense.  AJAX is just Javascript that talks to a server.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29).

The easiest way to do that is to use jQuery and its `$.ajax` method.

See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

It's as simple as

```
$('a.upvote-button').click(function() {
  $.ajax('/posts/123/upvote', {type: 'post'});
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need javascript (or something considerably less sane) to do this.  Namely, you need an AJAX callback.

> I'm not that big of a fan of letting users see the source for my functions.

The client-side source of your "function" would be ridiculously simple.  It could be as simple as:

```
$.post('/1234567/vote/up')
```

You may use a direct link to a php script (and form post values) instead, and without a javascript library it would be a few more lines, but you shouldn't need to expose anything of value in your javascript.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into this. It does seem really simple.

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript. JQuery is an excellent choice for manipulating on screen content and interacting with a server via asynchronous calls.